# Open NSURL with safari in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, nsurl

I have this code to open url in safari:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]];
```

but it only works on **iOS9**, and **iOS8** it doesn't work.
Anybody have a clue what this can be?

Thanks

Comment: Define "Doesn't work". "Doesn't work" is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: Where you are testing on device or simulator  and which xcode version?

Answer (score 3):

In **Objective C**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some url"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use SFSafariViewController for iOS 9. Also use https instead of http. Test in device.

```
if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {
        SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
        sfvc.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL]) {
            //NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[URL description]);
        }
    }
```